# ROS - find_package - MSG in other local package

Tags: cmake, ros, msg

I work on ROS and I am blocked in CMAKE step.
So explain

```
build
devel
src
  package_a
    node_a
      source
        node_a.cpp
    CMakeList.txt
    package.xml
  package_b
    msg
      msg_between_a_b.msg
    node_b
      source
        node_b.cpp
    CMakeList.txt
    package.xml
```

I am blocked in the step of CMakeList.txt for package_a.
Package a need to know the message defined in package_b.

Error message from TERM console.

> Add the installation prefix of "package_b" to CMAKE_PREFIX or set
> "package_b_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
> "package_b" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
> has been installed.

***I am (very) interesting of "package_b_DIR".***

That is what I write in CMalkeList.txt:

```
# SEARCH package that already EXIST in /opt/ros
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
 message_generation
 rostime
 roscpp
 std_msgs
 rosconsole
 roscpp_serialization)

# Add package PACKAGE_B (usefull) for MSG
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  package_b)
```

***Very very thanks in advance !***

Comment: Whats the CMakeList of package_b ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved

**1. ROS shall find package_b.**

If true, you can find this file via this command:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*Config.cmake"
```

**Result:**

> ./build/package_b/catkin_generated/installspace/package_bConfig.cmake

> ./devel/share/package_b/cmake/package_bConfig.cmake

If not, open CMakeList.txt and check IF:

```
catkin_package(
)
```

Check success of build via catkin_make.

**2. Inform that package a need package b**

After inform package_a that need package_b.
This information is in the package.xml of package_a:

Find <build_depend> and inform that need package_b.

```
<build_depend>package_b</build_depend>
```